# Merge two datatables with check c#

Tags: c#, datatable

I am having two datatables as below,

```
dtOrigin
RowId Stk   ProdName
 2     245   ABC
 4     144   XYZ
 5     122   ADE


dt1
RowId Stk
 2     2
 4     7
```

I need to merge this two datatables to produce below result, basically if rowid exist in dt1, need to minus its stock qty from dtOrigin
dtNew

```
RowId Stk           ProdName
 2     243(245-2)   ABC
 4     137(144-7)   XYZ
 5     122          ADE
```

I am able to do this with loop, but is there anyway to do this without loop
Thanks

```
                    var JoinResult = (from p in dt1.AsEnumerable()
                                      join t in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                                      on p.Field<string>("RowID") equals t.Field<string>("RowID")
                                      into joinedtables from stuff in joinedtables.DefaultIfEmpty()
 select new
                                      {
----------------,
----------------,
Stock = p.Field<Int32>("Stk") - stuff.Field<Int32>("Stk")
}
```

Throwing exception. Can you please correct?

---

Below is the code I a using

```
    var JoinResult = (from p in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                      join t in dt2.AsEnumerable()
                                      on p.Field<string>("RowID") equals t.Field<string>("RowID")
                                      into joinedtables from stuff in joinedtables.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                      select new
                                      {
                                          RowID = p.Field<string>("RowID"),
                                          ProdName = p.Field<string>("ProdName"),
                      STK = p.Field<Int32>("STK") - stuff?.Field<Int32>("STK") ?? 0
                                         }

  dtable = LINQResultToDataTable(JoinResult);




    public static DataTable LINQResultToDataTable<T>(IEnumerable<T> Linqlist)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();


            PropertyInfo[] columns = null;

            if (Linqlist == null) return dt;

            foreach (T Record in Linqlist)
            {

                if (columns == null)
                {
                    columns = ((Type)Record.GetType()).GetProperties();
                    foreach (PropertyInfo GetProperty in columns)
                    {
                        Type IcolType = GetProperty.PropertyType;

                        if ((IcolType.IsGenericType) && (IcolType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()
                        == typeof(Nullable<>)))
                        {
                            IcolType = IcolType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                        }

                        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(GetProperty.Name, IcolType));
                    }
                }

                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

                foreach (PropertyInfo p in columns)
                {
                    dr[p.Name] = p.GetValue(Record, null) == null ? DBNull.Value : p.GetValue
                    (Record, null);
                }

                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

Comment: If you are using linq to sql then you can use linq join expression

Comment: What exception is it throwing? `NullReferenceException`? `InvalidArgumentException`? `BetweenKeyboardAndChairException`? It is almost impossible for anyone to help if you don't provide enough detail.

Comment: @ZevSpitz, the exception is {"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: row"}

Comment: if I perform simple inner join it works, but I need this with left join

Comment: What if the row exists in the second datatable but not in the first? Also, is it possible for there to be multiple records with the same `RowID` in the same datatable?

Comment: 1. this might be the case that row exists in 2nd datatable but not in first. Then it should not display that in final datatable. All records in first and matching from second.
2. No RowID is unique in datatable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var JoinResult = 
                 ...
                 select new {
                     ...
                     Stock = p.Field<Int32>("Stk") - (stuff?.Field<Int32>("Stk") ?? 0)
                 };
```

I'm guessing that when there is no matching record in the second datatable, `stuff` will be `null`, causing a `NullReferenceException` when trying to read the value for that row. This expression:

```
stuff?.Field<Int32>("Stk")
```

means "if `stuff` is `null`, then the whole expression should evaluate to `null`, otherwise it should return the value from the field."

That is still not enoguh; because you can't subtract `null` from something else. It needs to be passed to the `??` operator:

```
stuff?.Field<Int32>("Stk") ?? 0
```

which means that if the left side is not `null` then use that value, otherwise use 0.

Comment: It is working partially. I mean if the RowId exist in both table it deducts the Stk and displays correctly, but those products which are not in second table but are present in 1st table always display STK = 0, even if first table has value for STK

Comment: @JohnyBravo Try wrapping in parentheses: `STK = p.Field<Int32>("STK") - (stuff?.Field<Int32>("STK") ?? 0)`